# adjust divs in html

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have 3 tables each of width 300px. Tables can be collapsed or visible. I have to arrange them in such a way that if there is only one table visible it comes at the center of the page (i.e. the tables should be centrally aligned). Also, tables should adjust their position depending on the size of the screen.
For example -  if the screen size is 1300px , all the three tables should come horizontally, if the screen size is 700px, two tables should come side by side and one should come below them.

Things tried :

1. I have tried making a container and making it centrally aligned and that didn't work.
2. I have also tried making a table which contains these three tables but I am unable to position them depending on the size of the screen (horizontal scroll comes if screen size decreases and I don't want that)

Comment: CSS with media queries should be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of bootstrap if possible, they provide wonderful grid system which is what you need. It is great for responsive designs and simply works by assigning classes to elements. Read about it "http://getbootstrap.com/css/"

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto;width: 95%;">
<div style="display: inline-block; width:300px">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block; width:300px">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block; width:300px">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```